# How come some wild Pokemon appear at levels over level 100?

Tags: pokemon-series

How come some wild Pokemon are over level-100, but you can only train up to level 100?

Comment: Which game in the series are you talking about here?

Answer (score 7):

It's a glitch. Level cap is 100 and you can't go above, wild or not.

> By exploiting the old man glitch in Generation I, a Pokémon can be acquired at a level higher than 100. Also in Generation I, any Pokémon can also be raised to a level above 100 via the Pokémon merge glitch; however, Pokémon in the Slow experience group need to be merged with a glitch Pokémon who requires even more experience at level 100. These Pokémon can continue to be leveled up with Rare Candies until level 255. Whenever a Pokémon over level 100 gains any amount of experience, its level will revert to 100, and if a Rare Candy is fed to a level 255 Pokémon, it will revert to level 0.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Level#Level_cap)